# php - make a function available in a namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I am kind of new to php namespaces and I would like to know if the following is possible:

I have a function `my_function` that I would like to be available only inside of the classes of a single namespace.

For example, in a file `helpers.php` I have

```
function my_function() {
    return 'something';
}
```

In `fileA`

```
namespace my_namespace
class A {}
```

In `fileB`

```
namespace my_namespace
class B {}
```

In `fileC`

```
namespace other_namespace
class C {}
```

Is there a way to have the function `my_function` available inside classes A and B, but not inside class C?

It's kind of a curiosity, to better understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not what namespaces are for.

As described in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php):

> In the PHP world, namespaces are designed to solve two problems that authors of libraries and applications encounter when creating re-usable code elements such as classes or functions:
>
> 1. Name collisions between code you create, and internal PHP classes/functions/constants or third-party classes/functions/constants.
> 2. Ability to alias (or shorten) Extra_Long_Names designed to alleviate the first problem, improving readability of source code.
>
> PHP Namespaces provide a way in which to group related classes, interfaces, functions and constants.

With regards to your code: if there is no namespace in your `helpers.php` file then `my_function()` is added to the [Global space](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php) and can be called anywhere in your application as written.

If you declare the function in `fileA` then it can be called from anywhere in your application using `\my_namespace\my_function()`.